# Spring MVC resource not available error

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have created a simple MVC application in Netbeans7.3 . I have created two JSP pages and one servlet and one POJO.I cannot be able to link all these files I think there is a error in Web.xml file.Please help me.

Where should I put my redirect.jsp page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Controller</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Controller.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC is having concept called as view resolver to be placed in the spring configuration file.

below mentioned is one of the example for the same, here we are using free marker but you will get the idea of prefix and postfix notation.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
        <property name="prefix" value="" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl" />
        <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="rc" />
    </bean>
```

Note : you will need jsp view resolver and suffix will be .jsp instead of .ftl

When controller method returns string it is mapped to prefix and postfix by which the jsp page is displayed. in the example listed above when the method is returning string "abc" it will search for 
abc.ftl page in your WEB-INF directory.